# Python Rand function

Tags: python, statistics, julia, simulation

**Background**

In Julia programming we have a Rand function which sintaxis is :

> rand([rng=GLOBAL_RNG], [S], [dims...])

which pick a random element or array of random elements from the set of values specified by S and gives an array of dimension of the third arg.

**Question**

I want to apply the same logic to make a simulation for an assurance policy problems:

```
m = 60000
n = len(policy.AGE)
k=1/10
@time begin
    Death = zeros(Bool, m, n)
    Accident = rand(Bernoulli(k), m, n)
```

Which is Julia Code, but when taking this to python i don't find the correct form of **rand(Bernoulli(k), m, n)**

I know to simulate a Bernoulli is just **bernoulli.rvs(k,n)** but the part that **set of values specified by S and gives an array of dimension of the third arg.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `size` keyword argument of `rvs`:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import bernoulli
>>> bernoulli.rvs(0.25, size=10)
array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: I know that,  but how do i specify to take the values from another set of values specified?

Comment: I do not understand the question then. Just rewrite `rand(Bernoulli(q[policy.AGE[j]]), m)` as `bernoulli.rvs(q[policy.AGE[j]], size=m)` assuming `q[policy.AGE[j]]` would also work in Python (you have not shown the Python implementation you use).